# How can I correctly test to see if the model I'm passing to my controller is of a particular type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with multiple forms on it.  These forms have partial views which are added using Html.RenderPartial(). I want to be able to distinguish between the models in a single actionResult thusly:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(dynamic Model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Model is RegisterModel)
        {
            Register((RegisterModel)Model, returnUrl);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Is there any reason why this doesn't work? I have also tried typing Model as an object instead of a dynamic but that didn't help either.  Model.GetType() always returns object, and Model is RegisterModel always returns false.  What am I missing about MVC3's behavior that I need to understand here? Thank you for your time

Comment: what returns Model.GetType().Name? BTW why you using dynamic as model type?

Comment: Not familiar with MVC but could you make that a Generic function?  Like LogOn<T>(T Model, string returnUrl)?

Comment: Model.GetType().Name returns as "Object".  I used a dynamic as a model type because I was led to believe that MVC3 uses dynamics alot, and object wasn't working. So I thought I'd give it a shot. I don't know enough about the nuts and bolts of mvc3 to know what actually gets passed here and why the is keyword wouldn't work in this situation

Comment: who is calling LogOn method? Why you think that Model should be of specific type and not someting raw boxed/wrapped as object?

Comment: I'm not sure that's not what's going on.  I just wanted something that was a better solution than try/catch and to understand the behavior of MVC3 correctly. It is called automatically when a form post is done on that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, why dont create different Action Methods for different ModelTypes ? 
This would result in better performance and better "seperation of concern."
But if you want to do this the way you describe, try this...

Maybe this sounds strange but

> *It is statically-typed as a dynamic type.*

You can create a Custom Model Binder that tryes to bind your
POST or GET informations to the type that you want.

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object result;
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // custom logic sample
        if (request.Params["ParamName"].ToString() == "xyz")
        {
            result = new RegisterModel();
            result.Propertie1 = request.Params["Propertie1"];
        }
        else
        {
            // create another model
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] object Model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (Model is RegisterModel)
    {
        Register((RegisterModel)Model, returnUrl);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Scott Hanselman wrote a nice Blog Post about the dynamic keyword:
[C# 4 and the dynamic keyword](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx)

More informations about IModelBinder: [ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binding](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)

**hope this helps**

Comment: Yes I understand that, but according to msdn something of a dynamic type should work with is and produce true in this situation if the object passed in is castable as a RegisterModel (if I am understanding correctly)

Comment: I changed my answer a few seconds before i saw your comment. Does this now helps you ?

Comment: if you look at my original question, i have actually tried object with  the same results. Also dynamic is used in the same way here with success http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx I think the issue has something to do with what mvc3 actually passes to its action

Comment: Thats right. MVC does tryes to bind the information to your type. So you can create a ModelBinder class that create the right type for you. i will change my answer now.

Comment: That looks very helpful, in the interest of correctly following the mvc pattern, where would this class go? does it qualify as a model?

Comment: The real MVC way is to have different Action Methods for different Model Types. My answer is updated